# GET weird error while installing strapi using Command (npx create-strapi-app@latest) my-project in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, strapi

```
PS C:\Users\Rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\E-commerce\api> npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project
? Choose your installation type Quickstart (recommended)
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at C:\Users\Rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\E-commerce\api\my-project.
Creating files.
Error while installing dependencies:
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.
npm WARN config 
npm WARN config     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! 94340000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-29T15_26_07_183Z-debug-0.log
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBreadcrumb')
    at C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:67:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at captureStderr (C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:66:14)
    at createProject (C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-project.js:136:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)  
    at async createQuickStartProject (C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-quickstart-project.js:21:5)
```

Unable to find any solution regarding this on internet. I'm using node v16.19.0 and npm v8.19.3 during that time.

Comment: A search for that error reveals https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41056. There maybe something there that could help.